# Datastax: Block not found error from DSEFS

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Spark streaming job running in DSE using DSEFS for check-pointing directory. I see this error in debug log file. How to resolve this error?

```
ERROR [dsefs-netty-worker-5] 2017-12-01 05:23:02,679 DSE-FS RestServerHandler.scala:126 - [id: 0x9964e082, /<>:58874 :> 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5598] Streaming data to remote end failed.
java.io.IOException: Block not found a3859f30-aa23-11e7-80b9-4b8bdaf197cd
    at com.datastax.bdp.fs.server.blocks.BlockService$stateMachine$33$1.apply(BlockService.scala:706) ~[dsefs-server_2.10-5.0.19.jar:5.0.19]
    at com.datastax.bdp.fs.server.blocks.BlockService$stateMachine$33$1.apply(BlockService.scala:703) ~[dsefs-server_2.10-5.0.19.jar:5.0.19]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.10.6.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.bdp.fs.exec.SameThreadExecutionContext$class.executeInSameThread(SameThreadExecutionContext.scala:24) ~[dsefs-common_2.10-5.0.19.jar:5.0.19]
    at com.datastax.bdp.fs.exec.SameThreadExecutionContext$class.execute(SameThreadExecutionContext.scala:33) ~[dsefs-common_2.10-5.0.19.jar:5.0.19]
    at com.datastax.bdp.fs.exec.SerialExecutionContextProvider$$anon$5$$anon$2.execute(SerialExecutionContextProvider.scala:24) ~[dsefs-common_2.10-5.0.19.jar:5.0.19]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library-2.10.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) ~[scala-library-2.10.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) ~[scala-library-2.10.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) ~[scala-library-2.10.6.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.bdp.fs.server.blocks.BlockService$stateMachine$1$1.apply(BlockService.scala:60) ~[dsefs-server_2.10-5.0.19.jar:5.0.19]
    at com.datastax.bdp.fs.server.blocks.BlockService$stateMachine$1$1.apply(BlockService.scala:60) ~[dsefs-server_2.10-5.0.19.jar:5.0.19]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.10.6.jar:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358) [netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357) [netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112) [netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

Answer (score 2):

This error means DSEFS server failed to find metadata of the data block in the `dsefs.blocks` Cassandra table. The ids of the file blocks are stored in the `dsefs.block_offsets` table and they reference blocks stored in `dsefs.blocks`. If a row exists in `dsefs.block_offsets` and points to the block id that is absent in `dsefs.blocks`, you get this error when reading the file.

This error should not happen under normal circumstances and it means the filesystem metadata somehow got into inconsistent state. This may be a bug in the DSEFS implementation, a result of a data loss caused by setting up dsefs keyspace with insufficient replication factor or a result of a write operation that did not finish successfully and was applied only partially.

Please make sure you set dsefs keyspace RF to at least 3 and run `nodetool repair` to avoid accidental data loss or unavailability of some DSEFS metadata.

If this doesn't help, please contact me directly or through DataStax technical support and provide more details, including logs from the time before the error and  more context on what the job was doing when the failure occurred.

Comment: cqlsh:dsefs> select * from blocks where block_id=a3859f30-aa23-11e7-80b9-4b8bdaf197cd;

This query returned zero records.

When I run this query 
cqlsh:dsefs> select * from block_offsets where valid_until='9999-12-31 18:59:59-0500' and offset =0 and block_id=a3859f30-aa23-11e7-80b9-4b8bdaf197cd ALLOW FILTERING;

I am getting the following error:
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}

Comment: Also regarding RF I see the value being 2. 
CREATE KEYSPACE dsefs WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;

This value we'll increase to 3.

Can you please check on the error in the previous comment.

Comment: As for the error you got, you need to look in the system.log of your nodes.